# How do I migrate Office 2008 to a new Mac without using the Migration Assistant?

Tags: microsoft-office, migration, office-for-mac, microsoft-office-2008

I'm setting up a new Mac and want to start fresh with settings and apps so I'm selectively copying my user documents over and installing only the apps I need on the new Mac.

I'm running into a problem with Office 2008. I have a license for Office 2008 but Microsoft's site doesn't let me download the installer after the first 30 days passes (yes, that's the last time I buy anything from them as a digital download). So I moved the application directory over but whenever I try to use the help (like for function help in Excel), the app says that "Microsoft Help Viewer cannot be opened" and "Microsoft Help Viewer might not be properly installed on your computer. To restore it, reinstall your Microsoft application".

My question is: what files/directories need to copied to the new Mac to make sure I've got everything that Office needs to run. Answers that insist I need to use the migration assistant aren't helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft provides [support articles that describe how to manually completely remove Office 2008 from your Mac](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2500821). Instead of deleting those files, move them onto your new Mac in the exact same location.

Some files are removed using an uninstaller (sorry about that, I only used the 2011 instructions before). Read the [corresponding Office 2011 article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2398768) and check to see if the files mentioned there (e.g. `/Library/Application Support/Microsoft`) exist on you machine too, and copy them over to your new Mac.